# How do I create an arraylist in and add and view it with buttons?

Tags: user-interface, arraylist, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm trying to make a GUI program that enters and removes cars from an arraylist and displays the cars using JButtons. I am unable to get the arraylist to print from clicking on one of the buttons. I'm also unsure if my arraylist is made correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;


public class Window extends JFrame {

    public Window() {
    super ("Rent-a-Car");

    setSize(400, 100);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JButton b1 = new JButton("Add Car");
    JButton b2 = new JButton("Rent Car");
    JButton b3 = new JButton("Library");

    p.add(b1);
    p.add(b2);
    p.add(b3);

    add(p);

    final ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();
    cars.add("Audi");
    cars.add("VolksWagon");
    cars.add("Mercedes");
    cars.add("BMW");
    cars.add("Ford");
    cars.add("Subaru");
    cars.add("Lexus");
    cars.add("Acura");
    cars.add("Nissan");

    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter car model");
            String model = sc.next();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Car added");
            cars.add(model);

        }

    });


    /*b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for(int i=0 < cars.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    });*/


    }
}
```

Comment: Your structure is out of order. rearrange them might solve some of your issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ActionListener` for `b1` you're trying to scan it from the wrong place. If you run this, you've probably noticed that the JOptionPane doesn't do anything when you submit a car with the add button. However, if you enter a string into the terminal, an dialog will pop up saying "Car added". This is because Scanner sc is scanning `System.in`! This is not meant for GUIs.

Fortunately, it's really simple to get input from a `JOptionPane`.

**EDIT**: Added a few things like a JTextArea in a JScrollPane that is easy to append to and changed it to a simple GridLayout.

I also moved the ActionListeners into an inner class so that you don't clutter up your code with anonymous functions everywhere. It's also a bit easier to add stuff with the (e.getSource()) conditionals, too.

Set model equal to the result of `showInputDialog` as such:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Window extends JFrame {
    private JPanel p;
    private JButton b1, b2, b3;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private ArrayList<String> cars;

    public Window() {
        super ("Rent-a-Car");
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        setSize(400, 100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        p = new JPanel();
        b1 = new JButton("Add Car");
        b2 = new JButton("Rent Car");
        b3 = new JButton("Library");
        b1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        b2.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        b3.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        textArea = new JTextArea("");
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        p.add(b1);
        p.add(b2);
        p.add(b3);

        add(p);
        //add(textArea);
        add(scrollPane);

        cars = new ArrayList<String>();
        cars.add("Audi");
        cars.add("VolksWagon");
        cars.add("Mercedes");
        cars.add("BMW");
        cars.add("Ford");
        cars.add("Subaru");
        cars.add("Lexus");
        cars.add("Acura");
        cars.add("Nissan");
    }

    public void displayText(String s) {
        textArea.append(s + "\n");
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == b1) {
                String model = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter car model");
                cars.add(model);
                displayText("Added car: " + model);
            }
            else if (e.getSource() == b2) {
                //add something later
            }
            else if (e.getSource() == b3) {
                for (String car : cars) {
                    displayText(car);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3029889 I added a couple of things that should get you started on what you want to do!